# ImageReader maxImages (2) has already been acquired in background task

Tags: java, android

I am using ImageReader with Handler in order to get image in background.
But i am getting:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   maxImages (2) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.

```
 private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), CameraFragment.this));
    }

};
```

On my background task is :

```
    private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

    /**
     * The JPEG image
     */
    private final Image mImage;

    BaseCameraFragment cameraFragmentContext;

    public ImageSaver(Image image, BaseCameraFragment cameraFragmentContext) {
        mImage = image;
        this.cameraFragmentContext = cameraFragmentContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        cameraFragmentContext.photoReady(new ByteBufferInputStream(buffer));
        mImage.close();
    }

}
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Hey did you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

`

```
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image img = mReader.acquireLatestImage();

        //mReader.close();
       img.close();
    }
};
```

`

just use `img.close();` can solution it

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the issue. The error actually pops up only in very few devices but img.close() making issues in phones in which the camera works fine before